# Как правильно построить маппинг в hibernate и возможно ли вообще

Tags: java, hibernate

Имеются две таблицы в бд (order и orderdetail) следующего вида:

[image: структура таблицы order]

[image: структура таблицы orderdetail]

Имеется класс order:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос - можно ли при помощи hibernate построить маппинг поля parts где Long - id продукта а Integer - кол-во? Интересует выход именно из конкретной ситтуации.
Переписывать сущность крайне не желательно!

Answer (score 0):

Решение которое меня устроило:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "orderdetail",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
@MapKeyColumn(name = "product_id")
@Column(name = "count", table = "orderdetail")
private Map<Long, Integer> parts;
```